# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes when I connect a second monitor via HDMI (worked fine on 17.10)

Tags: multiple-monitors

My laptop uses Processor AMD® Turion(tm) ii p540 dual-core processor × 2 with graphics AMD® Rs880 (not suitable now for Windows 10). The laptop HD is partitioned for Windows 7 as a stand-by.

I came to Ubuntu in the final days of 17.10 and did not have this issue then.

The laptop uses an HDMI connection to a Toshiba TV monitor where the difficulty occurs. That is, when the TV monitor connects with the laptop at either booting-up or later, Ubuntu just freezes and requires a forced release of the power button. The Multi-Monitors dialog box indicates 'On' for all selections but the 'Aptupdateindicator' does not work. However when using the stand-by W7 OS both the HDMI connection & the TV monitor operate properly and without adjustment i.e. the TV just mirrors the laptop display automatically.

Since Ubuntu 17.10, Windows 7 and previously Windows 10 all connected over the HDMI to this TV monitor correctly, is there a tweak needed for 18.04 e.g. Aptupdateindicator not operating etc?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 uses wayland as the default server whereas in Ubuntu 18.04 xorg is the default. May be you can switch back to wayland. You should be able to choose by clicking the "gear" icon on the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for a speedy response regarding my multi-monitor snag.  I have tried your suggestion i.e. change to Wayland in the Log-in screen.  Unfortunately the snag still persists.  All I receive over the HDMI connection is the Ubuntu wallpaper but nothing else e.g. no cursor nor task bar etc.  When trying to revert to the image the laptop itself is using does not over-ride that being shown on the second screen. As a non-technical user, is there something missing in 18.04 that would quickly resolve this? There are no similar snags with the laptop's stand-by Windows 7 OS,it just connects over the HDMI automatically.  Kind regards. Tim